# Use WITH to loop over a set of data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, loops

Given the following fields below, I'm trying to loop to the first iteration of the total set of iterations.

```
+-------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
|           id      |     nextiterationId  |      iterationCount    | 
+-------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
|           110001  |             110002   |      0                 |
|           110002  |             110003   |      1                 |
|           110003  |             110004   |      2                 |
|           110004  |             1        |      3                 |
```

So if I call a SP/function using one of the values of the `id` field, I need it return the prior iterations of the id given until `iterationCount = 0`.

So If I use id of `110003`(send that as the parameter), the first thing it should query is an `id` field having a `nextIterationID` of `110003`. That would be the first loop.

Since the iterationCount is not 0 yet, it would keep looping. Then it would look for an id where `nextIterationID` is `110002` based on first loop determination, so second loop will find "id" of `110001` and return it. And since that record iterationCount = 0, it would stop the loop.

It's okay if I call the SP/function using `110003`, which is the 3rd iteration, and it would not return the `110004`, 4th iteration. I only need it to go back given the id.

A while ago I did this using a WITH and maybe WHILE using both somehow, but I can't recall how to do this now. I need the format returned in a way so that I can use it in a larger SELECT statements.

Comment: Which dbms ? Oracle ?

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a recursive cte solution. Let me know if it needs any tweaks.

```
--Throwing your table into a temp table
CREATE TABLE #yourTable (ID INT,NextIterationID INT,IterationCount INT)
INSERT INTO #yourTable
VALUES
    (110001,110002,0),
    (110002,110003,1),
    (110003,110004,2),
    (110004,1,3)

--Now for the actual work
--Here is your parameter
DECLARE @param INT = 110003;

--Recursive CTE
WITH yourCTE
AS
(
    --Initial Row
    SELECT  ID,
            NextIterationID,
            IterationCount
    FROM    #yourTable
    WHERE   NextIterationID = @param

    UNION ALL

    --Finding all previous iterations
    SELECT  #yourTable.*
    FROM    #yourTable
    INNER JOIN yourCTE
    ON yourcte.ID = #yourTable.NextIterationID
    --Where clause is not really necessary because once there are no more previous iterations, it will automatically stop
    --WHERE yourCTE.IterationCount >= 0
)

SELECT *
FROM yourCTE

--Cleanup
DROP TABLE #yourTable
```

Results:

```
ID          NextIterationID IterationCount
----------- --------------- --------------
110002      110003          1
110001      110002          0
```